# mySQL Как найти слово в строке?

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

В БД:

```
    id   vstavki
    1  фианит,топаз, бриллиант
    2  гранат,аметист
    3  раухтопаз
    4  аметист, топаз
    5  london-топаз, фианит
```

Мой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM price 
WHERE section=1 
AND price BETWEEN 600 AND 1500000 
AND size IN(16,16.5,17) 
AND material IN("Золото","Серебро") 
AND (vstavki LIKE "%Бриллиант%" OR vstavki LIKE "%Топаз%") 
group by nomer
```

Однако в вывод попадает раухтопаз. Как нужно написать запрос, чтобы раухтопаз не попадал в вывод при выборке по топаз?

Comment: убрать `%` в `vstavki LIKE "%Топаз%"`

Comment: тогда не попадут в вывод позиции id=1 id=4 id=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще так:

```
select *
  from price
 where lower(vstavki) regexp '(^|[^a-zа-яр-я])(топаз|бриллиант)([^a-zа-я]|$)';
```

НО, обратите внимание, мне в первые квадратные скобки, исключающие какие либо буквы перед словами пришлось кроме полного диапазона `а-я` включить еще и `р-я` без этого он постоянно находил "раухтопаз" потому, что считал букву "х" не в диапазоне `а-я`, но при этом отлично понял, что она в диапазоне `р-я` (я диапазон подобрал экспериментальным путем). С чем это может быть связано я не знаю. Но раз у него был один глюк с русскими буквами, может быть и еще какой нибудь. Т.е. я не дам 100% гарантию, что с произвольными словами он будет работать.

На всякий случая я применил там `lower` приводящий строку к маленьким буквам, поэтому искомые слова в регулярном выражении так же должны быть маленькими буквами, как вариант к ним так же можно применять `lower`.

Кроме того, вам возможно стоит поправить диапазоны букв-исключений под свое понимание что должно подпадать под понятие слитного слова, а что нет.

А вообще это повод задуматься о структуре базы, хотя бы при заполнении этого поля не позволять там писать все что угодно, а запрашивать каждый материал отдельно и самому формировать строку с правильными разделителями. Хотя если совсем по хорошему - должен быть справочник допустимых материалов вставок и к записи price табличка с отдельными записями лежащими вставками к данной строке price.

И еще, возможно, вам надо смотреть в сторону полнотекстового поиска sphinx или хотя бы [встроенного в MySQL](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html)

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: с окончанием ы не работает :( Подскажите как исправить.

Comment: добавьте явно букву `ы` в набор букв, который в конце, т.е. что то типа `([^a-zа-яы]|$)`. Хотя можно и туда добавить просто `р-я`, может как и в первой части поможет.

Comment: не проходит ни как (

Comment: видимо придется всё через LIKE переделывать.

Comment: Как и я говорил в ответе, лучше сделать таблицу с допустимыми значениями и позволять выбирать только из них, что бы разных написаний одного и того же не было, тогда можно будет писать их через фиксированный разделитель и искать на точное соответствие

Answer (score 0):

```
AND (vstavki LIKE "%Бриллиант%" OR vstavki LIKE "% Топаз%" OR vstavki LIKE "%,Топаз%") 
group by nomer
```

Добавьте перед "Топаз" пробел. Теперь будут выбиратся только слова, в которых фрагмент "Топаз" идёт сначала

**UPD**
Добавьте еще один вариант сравнения, с запятой без пробела, для совпадения в такой строке:

> 1  фианит,топаз, бриллиант

Comment: тоже вариант, но я надеялся на более короткий вариант, возможно с регуляркой.

Comment: @amijin, нужно было это указать в вопросе